# Imported Excel Spreadsheet not Filtering Column

Tags: filter, excel, import, spreadsheet

I am uploading an excel template to the SharePoint site. I have 8 different metrics and want to add a filter to a specific column.SharePoint automatically adds the filter option to certain columns, but not all.  The column I wish to add a filter to has just simple text (peoples names), but SharePoint does not add a filter to that column. Does anyone know how to add a filter or why SharePoint won't filter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By default, multi-line text columns cannot be filtered in a view. Check what data type the Excel column turns out after the it is loaded in SharePoint. You may want to make sure that it is a single line text field. It will also help if you create an index on the text column.